# Read data from access database and display in html webpage

Tags: html, database

[image: Access Database Image]

There is a Access Database file and HTML. I want to link or read the information/data from Access Database into HTML form and as the new information is added to the Access, the HTML should update and save the information. It should automatically create a new rows and column as the new data comes it. Also as I get the information from database, I can assign or update the progress level of each request we get.

I have tried this as a the last code to access or link the data from database to HTML but it didnt work.

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "Web Forms_BackEnd";
    
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass, $db);
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    $sql = "select * from date";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    
    //for single row
    $singleRow = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    
    print_r($singleRow);
    
    echo "<hr>";
    
    //for all records
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        print_r($row);
    }
    
    
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    table, td, th {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-color: black
        }
    </style>
    <style>
/* Style the body */
    body {
        font-family: Arial;
         margin: 5;
         }

/* Header/Logo Title */
    .header {
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        background: steelblue;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>IT Service Request Log</h1>
        </div>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <col style="width:3%">      <!-- ID -->
            <col style="width:4%">      <!-- Date -->
            <col style="width:7%">      <!-- Name -->
            <col style="width:9%">     <!-- Email -->
            <col style="width:15%">     <!-- Sunject -->
            <col style="width:25%">     <!-- Content -->
            <col style="width:5%">     <!-- Department -->
            <col style="width:2%">      <!-- Assigned To -->
            <col style="width:1%">      <!-- Priority -->
            <col style="width:1%">      <!-- Status -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Content</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Assigned To</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td algin="center">
                    <select>
                        <option value="Choose an Employee">Choose an Employee</option>
                        <option value="Dee">Dee</option>
                        <option value="Benito">Ben</option>
                        <option value="Avi">Allen</option>
                        <option value="Krish">Krish</option>
                        <option value="Roy">Roy</option>
                        <option value="Carlos">Carlos</option>
                        <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td algin="center">
                    <select>
                        <option value="Choose Priority">Choose Priority</option>
                        <option value="1. High">1. High</option>
                        <option value="2. Normal">2. Normal</option>
                        <option value="3. Low">3. Low</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td algin="center">
                    <select>
                        <option value="Choose Status">Choose Status</option>
                        <option value=" Open"> Open</option>
                        <option value=" In Progress"> In Porgress</option>
                        <option value=" Closed"> Closed</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```